# Report Modification in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

I want to modify the Katalon report: I need to change the Host Name in the Report.

Please provide the solution if any.

Thanks
KSK

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the automatically generated HTML report, you cannot do that in out-of-the-box Katalon Studio.

But, you can code your own solution with Groovy/Java and use it with Katalon.

*EDIT:*

If you are talking about the email report, you can go to `Project` > `Settings` > `Email` > `Template` and just remove the hostname.